# Microsoft Teams App Connector - Configure Screen won't load in-line in modal anymore

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

We are developing a MS Teams application (using incoming webhooks to deliver messages from our SaaS app into Teams) and have noticed that when creating new connectors using the MS Connectors Developer Dashboard (https://outlook.office.com/connectors/publish) the connector install process no longer functions as it used to.

Up until about a week ago, the connector install process involved the connector configuration page being loaded as an iframe within the teams app install modal. This is exactly as described and expected in the MS docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-creating

This install process should look like this:
[Working connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SSVh.png)

Currently, when creating connectors, the resulting install flow looks like this. (Notice how it no longer renders configuration screen in iframe, but instead links to it):
[Broken connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTvl1.png)

I have diff'ed the application manifest and confirmed the only difference in setup is the connector ID. I've also double checked that all the connector fields (valid domains, configuration URLs etc.) are exactly as before. The change seems to be on Microsoft side. My old connectors created earlier this month continue to work OK

My question is, what is this new install flow that I'm seeing and why is it suddenly showing up now? How can I tell Teams to go back to using the old install flow for my new connectors.

Other details that may be relevant:

- I've tried creating connectors in two separate MS Office accounts, both work the same way
- The app is NOT yet published, I'm testing locally by uploading and approving within our company's Teams account
- I've confirmed the configuration endpoint is viewable from the outside world and have found now network errors in the teams app that would explain it failing to load.

Comment: You can follow below documentation to create the incoming Webhook: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook

Comment: We have raised a bug for the same. The team is looking into it. We will let you know once the fix is available.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT is there anywhere i can track the progress of this bug? Also do you know if there is a work-around in the meantime.

Comment: @BeesNotIncluded - We cannot share it outside and You wont be having access to the work items.

Comment: Sorry to bug, but do you have an estimate of when this will be fixed/released? Thanks!

Comment: Currently we do not have any ETA. We will let you know once we have an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Teams support were able to confirm that there was an issue and that it was resolved and rolled out on March 15 2022. I have since confirmed that I am able to create and install teams apps.

Thank you to Meghana for keeping me in the loop about progress.